# Value in object getting cleared

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In a sample program  I did for studying MVC, I have a doubt. The code below is my sample.

**StudentClass**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewOne**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewOne";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td>
   </tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Name : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { name = "name"});
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnStart" class="button" value="Start Filling Details" />
}
```

**ViewTwo.cshtml**

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewTwo";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView"))
{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td>
</tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Age : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { name = "age" });
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnNext" class="button" value="Next" />
}
```

**MyViewController.cs**

```
public class MyViewController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ViewOne()
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        return View(student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewOne(Student student) // When comes here student contains value in name that I input.
    {
        return View("ViewTwo", student);
        //return RedirectToAction("ViewTwo",student);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewTwo(Student student) // But here the name in student cleared and only age is there. 
    {
        return View("ViewThree", student);
        //return RedirectToAction("ViewThree", student);
    }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your view two like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView"))
{
<table style="border-color:Black;">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td>
</tr>
</table>

<label>Enter Age : </label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { name = "age" });
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnNext" class="button" value="Next" />
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name);
}
```

Add `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name);`

In your view three, you have to add both `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name);` and `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Age);`

Comment: Thankx khanh. I have one more doubt, Suppose if the student have 20 or 30 properties, then I need to place hiddenfor for each property in every views ?, Is there any method to keep it as a whole student object instead of keeping as each property ?

Comment: @Arun: because web application is stateless, when you post a request to a server, the server does not remember the previous requests. If you're designing a multi-view and don't want to lose properties, I suggest using ajax technique. By using ajax, you **do not post the whole page to the server** and the information is stored on client side. When users reach the final view, you send all information to the server.

Comment: @Mohammad: please check the time, I posted before

Answer (score 3):

Put the Age and Place into `Hidden Field`...

Comment: Thankx, Suppose if the student have 20 or 30 properties, then I need to place hidden field for each property in every views ?, Is there any method to keep it as a whole student object instead of keeping as each property ?

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Hidden` returns an IHtmlString conaint a hidden field.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.Name);
```

or

```
<input type='hidden' value='@Model.Name' name="Name" />
```

so in your code:

```
@model MyTestMVCApp.Models.Student
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ViewTwo";
}  
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView"))
    {         
     @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.Name);
    <table style="border-color:Black;">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Place</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Name</td><td>@Model.Age</td><td>@Model.Place</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <label>Enter Age : </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { name = "age" });
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnNext" class="button" value="Next" />
     }
```

Comment: the hidden field must be put inside `@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView"))`, otherwise this code won't work

Comment: @Mohammad: `<input type='hidden' value='@Model.Name' />` won't work because it's missing the `name` attribute, also I don't see where you put your hidden field inside the `@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewTwo", "MyView"))`

Comment: <input type='hidden' value='@Model.Name' name="Name" /> that has name

Comment: @Mohammad: the name is for model mapping

Comment: What are you talking about?